# Delete with inner join Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

I have to perform a delete below is a noddy example of what I am trying to do

is sql I would do something like

```
DELETE FROM Customer
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT TOP Address.AddressId
    FROM Address
    JOIN Customer ON Address.CustomerId= Customer.CustomerId
    AND Address.AddressId='22'
    AND Customer.Type=1)
```

Kind of lost how you would do that using Entity Framework

any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You must query db first, load entities to your application and delete them in common EF way. If you have a lot of entities to delete it can be very complex operation. In such case it is better to use stored procedure.